# Where can I see Workflow History for my Task list?

Tags: workflow-activity

I have a Task list and I have workflows that run when items are added/changed to the Tasks list. For a NORMAL list I can just click on the context menu and see Workflows in the menu.  But for TASK lists, this menu item doesn't exist.  Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Oh.  Workflow History ->  All History.